# Missing phy0 wifi driver?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, lenovo

I was trying to install Ubuntu 14 beta 2 on my new laptop--a Lenovo Yoga Pro 2--and I couldn't use the wireless. So, I used `rfkill list all`, and got the result:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard Blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard Blocked: yes
2: hci0: Buetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard Blocked: no
```

However when I booted from the USB stick I had just installed from running `rfkill list all` output:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard Blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard Blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Buetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard Blocked: no
```

Using `sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop && sudo rfkill unblock all` got the wireless working.  And I can't figure out why phy0 isn't in the install there, how to load it in, or otherwise get the wireless working.

Comment: If you issue those commands, is the wireless working as expected? Are you asking how to make the change permanent?

Comment: If I issue the commands when booting from the USB stick the wireless will work, if I do a clean install and do them on the newly installed system it will not work.  It will not work because as mentioned above on the system rfkill shows 3 drivers, on the USB stick it shows 4, once the command is issued on the installed drive there simply isn't any wifi driver at all.

Comment: I think you have two problems here; the buggy ideapad_laptop and the wireless driver. What is your wireless card? lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 lspci -nn | grep 0280 produces: `01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 6b)`

Comment: Please check the log for errors: dmesg | grep iwl

Comment: results of `dmesg | grep iwl`:

    [    8.435931] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
    [    8.436014] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: irq 63 for MSI/MSI-X
    [    8.487783] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode' failed
    [    8.487788] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: no suitable firmware found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you install the latest firmware for your device. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/egrumbach/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
sudo modprobe -r iwlmvm
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Detach the ethernet and the wireless should now be working.